# google voice recognition source code

Tags: android, voice-recognition, android-4.2-jelly-bean

as google said new android "jelly bean" will contain voice recognition engine able to work offline. As new android source code have been opened I tried to look at and find source for voice recognition engine but without success.

So my question: is voice recognition engine source code a part of android 4.1.1 source code? Or it's something like separate app?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

Comment: The Google apps are not part of the operating system and generally not open source. Only way I see is to decompile the apk

Comment: stefan, thank you for the answer. But here [link]https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/+/refs/heads/android-4.1.1_r1/default.xml I can see several apps seemed to be included into Android code. Calculator, browser, etc. I just want to be sure that voice recognition engine is not included. I can't see it in manifest. But may be I should look somewhere else?

Comment: probably there's allready someone trying to decompile this app. You might be lucky at xda-developers.com in the general android development section.

Comment: but it's definitely NOT open source? This is what I want to find out.

Comment: One of the engines is already there and it was there since Android 1.0 (external/srec). It's pretty good engine developed for quite a long time and finally landed in Nuance from which it was licensed to Google. The models included are only English though and quite big parts of the engine are missing. I'm only not sure that this engine is indeed used for the new offline recognition feature.

Answer (score 5):

It is actually a downloadable package in settings. No apps and such, just a simple engine that the os falls back on if there is no internet.

So no, it is not part of the source code nor is it a separate app.
Hope my understanding of it is clear and has helped you.

Answer (score 0):

In Android 4.1 source you can see the speech engine source in srec_jni folder (C++ code) but there is some problem the header files are not located where it should be

Answer (score -1):

The voice recognition software definitely lies inside the Jellybean OS since the app recognizes the voice commands such as "call" it also recognized the names in the contact, hence the source code must be inside the OS.
P.S: Try switching off your wifi and Mobile data and voice commanding "call" and it will work.